# JavaScript points

Tags: javascript, html, css

JavaScript. So i have a bit of problem here. I'm trying to make game, but im stuck with points. When you win this game first time, you get a 1 point, but every other time its not giving a point. Can you help me finding problem? I bold these point lines. Its the last 2 "if" lines

```
  function war(){
        var dealer = document.getElementById("dealer");
        var player = document.getElementById("player"); 
        var winner = document.getElementById("winner");
        var screen = document.getElementById("points");
        var points = 10;
        var win = lose;
        var lose = win;
        var dealercard = Math.floor(Math.random() *10)+1;
        var playercard = Math.floor(Math.random() *10)+1;
        dealer.innerHTML = dealercard;
        player.innerHTML = playercard;


    if(dealercard > playercard){
        winner.style.color ="red";  
        winner.innerHTML = "You lost.";
    }
     else{
        winner.style.color ="green";
        winner.innerHTML = "You won.";
    }
    if (dealercard == playercard){
        winner.style.color ="blue";
        winner.innerHTML = "WAR"
    }

        **if(dealercard < playercard){
            win = points + 1;
            screen.innerHTML = win;
        }

        if(dealercard == playercard){
            win = points + 1;
            screen.innerHTML = win;
        }**


    }
```

Comment: To add an incremental value to a pre-specified value declared in an existing variable, use the `+=` addition assignment operator, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Addition_assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not incrementing the `points` variable, so everytime you do this:

```
win = points + 1;
screen.innerHTML = win;
```

you will get 11.

Try this:

```
points += 1
win = points;
screen.innerHTML = win;
```

Answer (score 0):

mike_t beat me to the answer, but here is a working demo for what he suggested:

```js
var points = 10;

function war() {
  var dealer = document.getElementById("dealer");
  var player = document.getElementById("player");
  var winner = document.getElementById("winner");
  var screen = document.getElementById("points");
  var win = lose;
  var lose = win;
  var dealercard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  var playercard = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1;
  dealer.innerHTML = dealercard;
  player.innerHTML = playercard;


  if (dealercard > playercard) {
    winner.style.color = "red";
    winner.innerHTML = "You lost.";
  } else {
    winner.style.color = "green";
    winner.innerHTML = "You won.";
  }
  if (dealercard == playercard) {
    winner.style.color = "blue";
    winner.innerHTML = "WAR"
  }

  if (dealercard < playercard) {
    points = points + 1;
    screen.innerHTML = points;
  }

  if (dealercard == playercard) {
    points = points + 1;
    screen.innerHTML = points;
  }


}
```

```html
Dealer: <span id="dealer"></span><br> Player: <span id="player"></span><br> Winner: <span id="winner"></span><br> Points: <span id="points"></span><br>

<button onclick="war()">War!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several things wrong with this code, and I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve.

But here are a few pointers:

1. The points variable is defined inside the function and initialized to `10`. This means everytime the function is called points start again at `10`. Consider using a global variable.
2. `var win = lose;` followed by `var lose = win;` does not really make sense. Can you explain what was the intention?

I hope this helps a bit, if no you will have to provide more details.